# Update open graph with a user generated image depending on url string query with javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph

Here is what I want to do :

1. Have a website with some parameters, generating a custom div
2. Let the user share its custom result with an url like mysite.com?parameter1=1520&param2=1820
3. Let the user share this link to facebook/Twitter/etc...
4. I'd like the Facebook/Twitter sharing to show an image of the custom div

I can do steps 1,2,3 and I can turn my div into a canvas, and my canvas into a PNG if needed. 
What I don't know is how to make the open graphe image tag of mysite.com?parameter1=1520&param2=1820 to be an image generated by these parameters. Do I absolutely need to save it on my server ? and how ?

Could you point me towards the right direction ?
Thanks in advance,
Adrien

Comment: You don’t necessarily need to save a physical copy of it on you server - but you need to provide HTTP(S) URLs that when requested return the appropriate data. // Client-side JavaScript won’t do you any good here, the Facebook scraper doesn’t care for it. Your server must return the appropriate data when those URLs are requested.

Comment: Ok, so my question is how do I use a canvas as opengraph image ?

Comment: That is not directly possible. You would need to get the binary image data, send it to your server and store it there somewhere, so that it can then be requested via an HTTP(S) URL afterwards, like a “normal” image.

Comment: It might be possible adapting this code : https://github.com/lukasz-madon/heroesgenerator